# Ruby: Calculate sum of all node values of a binary tree

Tags: ruby, sum, binary-tree

I have a binary tree implementation as below. I'd like to add a method that recursively sums up all node values of the binary tree:

```
class BST

  class Node
    attr_reader :value, :left, :right

    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
      @left = nil
      @right = nil
    end

    def insert(value)
      if value <= @value
        @left.nil? ? @left = Node.new(value) : @left.insert(value)
      elsif value > @value
        @right.nil? ? @right = Node.new(value) : @right.insert(value)
      end
    end

  end

  def initialize
    @root = nil
  end

  def insert(value)
    @root.nil? ? @root = Node.new(value) : @root.insert(value)
  end

end
```

I found the answer for other languages, however unfortunately not for Ruby.

Comment: What do you mean, you found the answer for other languages but not for Ruby? The logic is exactly the same. What specifically is the obstacle you are facing in implementing it?

Comment: @Amadan I'm a beginner and trying to understand recursion. While I do understand the principle, I'm unable to transpose other languages' solution into Ruby...

Comment: The sum of a node is the the node's value plus the sum of all non-nil children, right? At least attempt to translate it into code, then we can talk about what is wrong with it, if anything.

Comment: A good start would be to add an example of a tree (and show the value of the desired sum). As there are no answers yet you might consider deleting the question, edit to clarify and add an example, then undelete. That way you won't feel time pressure to complete the edit and won't attract more downvotes or votes to close while you are editing. SO has a rule that, for homework problems (not suggesting this is one), the asker is expected to explain efforts he/she has made to solve the problem. That does not necessarily require code. It's potentially a good question.

Comment: Re: "The sum of a node is the the node's value plus the sum of all non-nil children, right? At least attempt to translate it into code". Here is what I tried inside the BST class:


  `def sum(node=@root)
    return if node.nil?
    total += node.value
    sum(node.left)
    sum(node.right)
  end`

however it throws "NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass". This is where I get stuck.

Comment: In general, try to write code in questions/answers, as code in comments that is longer than one line is superhard to read. If you must, then use `;` (or whatever is appropriate in your language) to separate the statements. I'll try to answer based on what I think you meant...

Answer (score 0):

I think your code in the comments was:

```
def sum(node=@root)
  return if node.nil?
  total += node.value
  sum(node.left)
  sum(node.right)
end
```

The idea is almost okay. There is no summing in `nil` nodes; and you total up the current node's value, the left node and the right node. Here's the mistakes:

- `total += node.value` is the first time we see `total`. This initialises it to `nil`. When you try to add `node.value` to it, you get the error you described. To avoid it, either `total` must already exist, or you can just *assign* `node.value` to it.
- If a function ends without executing a `return` statement, it returns the last evaluated expression; in this case, `sum(node.right)`. Wouldn't it be better if `sum` returned `total`?
- Conversely, `sum(node.left)` will presumably do some summing... but its return value is discarded. It might make sense to add it to the `total`. Speaking of totals, maybe we should do the same for `sum(node.right)`.
- Finally, `return if node.nil?` says you refuse to sum the nodes that are not actually nodes. That's great... except that `return` returns `nil`, and if you try to total a `nil` with something, it doesn't go well. There are two solutions here: refuse to total a node *before* you enter it, or say that a nil node has value 0, which does not affect a sum.

Taking it all together, here's my two versions:

```
# refuse to enter a nil node:
def sum(node=@root)
  total = node.value
  total += sum(node.left) unless node.left.nil?
  total += sum(node.right) unless node.right.nil?
  total
end

# treat nil nodes as if they were zeroes:
def sum(node=@root)
  return 0 if node.nil?
  node.value + sum(node.left) + sum(node.right)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! It explains exactly all the issues that I was struggling with all along and had me scratch my head for days until I finally resorted to SO. Also thanks for guiding me through the usage of SO, thanks also to @ Cary !

P.S. My attempted upvote is not being recorded due to my too low reputation score... Thanks again - you were super helpful!